# Overfitting and COLT/Statistical Learning Theory

Tags: overfitting

The aspect of over-fitting is typically viewed from the perspective of both- accuracy and model complexity. 
To mitigate over-fitting, we usually have the practical approach of having k-fold validations, training-validation-test set.

Question: theoretically, can we leverage the Statistical Learning theory (COLT) to draw bounds on the confidence of how well learning has happened, 
and how well classification can happen over unseen examples?

Example, many a time we consider the minimum number of samples (upper bound/sufficient samples) needed to learn (VC Dimension). 
Agreed, it is an overestimate, plus |H| or VC Dimension may be unknown in practice. 
The other perspective wherein, given the number of samples 'm', and 'delta' (probability of failure) -
we find error bound (on unseen examples)- Can we theoretically interpret this error bound to be an estimate of over-fitting? I get this intuition from Nello Cristianini's book on SVMs.

Appreciate any pointers.